# Adobe Captivate move Playbar to custom position on page

Tags: html, html5-canvas, adobe, adobe-captivate

Is it possible to move the playbar into a custom position on a slide not connected to the borders?

My company wants to migrate to captivate and we need to position the controls on a certain position in our slides, such as in the frame of the course.

Needs to be html5 compatible as well if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to E learning tools and had to dive into it as soon as my company realized I could do it for cheaper. Captivate is the only software I have looked into but so far to me it feels like wordpress in the sense that you can only do what it wants you to do. Not really much wiggle room. We like it because of html5 mobile support. Is camtasia better in terms of mobile support and wiggle room?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Camtasia has a production-preset that targets iPhone or Android platforms.  Camtasia has excellent wiggle room--maybe too much for your purposes.  It records and annotates (text,voice) anything on the computer screen.  But you're in charge of designing and displaying everything on the computer screen (no structured templates are available).  Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate the playbar using javascript, which you can set to execute when the first slide loads.

playbar.style.marginTop = "20px" will push it down a bit for example